# Thread halts program execution

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a program which has to run a 'watcher' function in the background, which checks if the time specified on an 'alarm' object equals to the current time, and if so, it triggers the alarm. This is the function:

```
def watcher(this):
    while this.run:
        this.lock.acquire(True)
        for i , a in enumerate(this.alarms):
            if a.activate:
                if a.repeat:              
                    if a.dateTime.minute + (a.dateTime.hour*60) == datetime.datetime.now().minute + (datetime.datetime.now().hour*60):
                        this.trigger(i)
                        while True:
                            if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
                                this.stop()
                                break

                elif a.dateTime.date() == datetime.datetime.now().date() and a.dateTime.minute + a.dateTime.hour*60 == datetime.datetime.now().minute + datetime.datetime.now().hour*60:
                        this.trigger(i)
                        while True:
                            if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
                                this.stop()
                                break
        this.lock.release()
```

The lock object is created previously inside the class this function is in.
It works when i run it on a program where i set the  alarms beforehand, but when i have to run another program alongside it that manipules the alarms, the other program hangs and only this one runs.

Here part of the main program:

```
import alarms
import datetime
import manager
import threading
import keyboard

lock = threading.Lock()
mngr = manager.manager()
print("Program Test")
tr = threading.Thread(target = mngr.watcher)
tr.start()
while True:

    command = input()

    if len(command) == 0:
        print('')
elif command.split()[0] == "rem":
        lock.acquire(True)
        try:
            mngr.remove_alarm(int(command.split()[1]) - 1)
        except IndexError as excp:
            print('Invalid alarm number. Use the command "list" to get alarms')
        except Exception as excp:
            print('Wrong usage of command: use like this: rem {alarmNumber}')
            print('DEBUG: ' + str(excp))
        finally:
            lock.release()
```

Am i doing the synchronization wrong? Upon even instancing the Thread on the main program it halts execution.

Comment: Python threading is not real multi-threading, only 1 instance of python can run at each time, due to the `GIL` - Global Interperted Lock, you should try multiprocess instead.